# Можно ли через тег  отправить post запрос?

Tags: html, php

```
[no-admins]
<form method="POST" action="">
<a name='bannacc'>
<div>Заблокировать пользователя</div>
</a>
</form>
[/no-admins]
```

Это желаемый код, но `<a>` предназначен для создания ссылок, есть ли какие-то хитрости?

Comment: Поставьте туда `input[type="submit"]` и стилизуйте как хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через **CSS**:

```
<style>
input[type="submit"]{
border:0;
padding:0;
background:none;
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
<form id=forma method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" value="Заблокировать пользователя">
</form>
```

Можно через **JavaScript**:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<a name='bannacc' onclick="this.parentNode.submit();return false;">
<div>Заблокировать пользователя</div>
</a>
</form>
```

Или если **<a>** не прямой наследник формы:

```
<form id=forma method="POST" action="">
<a name='bannacc' onclick="document.getElementById('forma').submit();return false;">
<div>Заблокировать пользователя</div>
</a>
</form>
```